# Import Variable Substitution Matrices based on string input Python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I am trying to import a substitution matrix to implement the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm in Python based on a given input.
If I want to select one Matrix I can do it like this:

```
from Bio.SubsMat import MatrixInfo as matlist
scoring_mat = matlist.blosum62
```

What would I have to do If I wanted to import any matrix based on an input? I have this for the moment:

```
def blosum(name):
    index = str(name)
    x= "blosum"+index
    return x

a= blosum(62)
scoring_mat = matlist.a
```

Unfortunately, it is giving me the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'Bio.SubsMat.MatrixInfo' has no attribute 'a'
```

What would I have to do to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try `scoring_mat = getattr(matlist,a)` instead. It worked for me.